# Where can I buy the four hard drive screws for my MacBook Pro 2011 15" (pic)

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive

I'm trying to find four replacement mounting screws for the 2.5" hard drive in my MacBook Pro 2011 15".

Here's a pic of the four screws [image] (one attached to hard drive).

I tried Googling and can't find anything. Are these screws available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find them, and most any other Apple repair parts, at [ifixit](http://www.ifixit.com/search?x=0&y=0&text=screws#10)

Comment: I looked on ifixit, even for my specific Mac, and the screws aren't included in the bundle, nor did I see them individually available :(

Comment: http://www.ifixit.com/MacBook-Parts/MacBook-Pro-15-Inch-Unibody-Mid-2009-Mid-2010-Early-2011-Hard-Drive-Bracket/IF161-036?utm_source=ifixit_cart&utm_medium=cart_product_link&utm_content=product_list

Comment: Thanks XQYZ. If you leave an answer I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 2):

[MacRecycling](http://mac.macrecycling.com/hard-dri...-p-101573.html) offers these screws as well. They seem to be quite pricey though!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the tutorials are suggesting T5's. Historically the proper Torx is a T8.

Regardless, they're meant only as pegs to stabilize the drive inside the body. You don't need these explicitly. So long as you have something with compatible threading and reach, it will function the same.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use a service called "The PowerBook Guy" which has morphed into Keane Mac Repair: http://www.keanesf.com/. Another resource for parts and fixing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In a pinch, I discovered that the lowly Q-Tip offers the perfect solution.  The shaft is the exact same diameter.  Just nip off the cotton, then insert the shaft fully into each hole, and cut with wire cutters allowing about 1/8" to stick out.  Works just great!